# Are Zerachiel and Sariel the same angel (according to orthodox churches)?

Tags: angels, judaism, oriental-orthodox, book-of-enoch

I know that Zerachiel and Sariel are both rather tied to Judaism as they are most prevalently found in the book of Enoch. In most denominations of christianity this book is not recognized as a canon, except for some oriental orthodox churches, which is why this question asks for the view from that specific branch.

Still, they seem to both be represented by the name *Saraqael* through various texts despite having different characteristics. I want to know this because Zerachiel seems to be a Seraphim and they both seem to be watchers. (Sariel might be a Seraphim too?)

Additional confusion was caused by references seemingly mixing up Sahariel (Hebrew: *god is my moon*) with Sariel (Hebrew: *god is my ruler*) and the existence of a Wikipedia article for both [Zerachiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zerachiel) (Hebrew: *god has remembered*) and [Sariel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sariel).

So are the angels called Zerachiel and Sariel the same, or did they just happen to share a similar name and rank?

Comment: This question requires to be scoped, as different Christian viewpoints will have different answers to the question. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to this aspect of this particular site. Welcome to SE-C. Which branch of Christianity do you wish to address ?

Comment: @NigelJ Because the book of Enoch is not recognized as a canon by most of the major denominations of christianity I did not know which specific one to address. Though I think it would be best to see it as being addressed to the orthodox denomination, as some orthodox churches recognize the book of Enoch.

Comment: . . . .  then I recommend an edit to your question in which you direct the question to that appropriate group.

Answer (score 2):

**Are Zerachiel and Sariel the same angel (according to orthodox churches)?**

The [Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_Orthodox_Tewahedo_Church) and the [Eritrean Orthodox Tewahedo Church](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eritrean_Orthodox_Tewahedo_Church) are the only churches that hold that their [Biblical Canon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_canon)
Extends to the [Book of Enoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch).

It is clear from their sources that the Angels Zerachiel and Sariel are separate identities, sharing the same angelic rank.

In the Coptic Orthodox tradition the [seven archangels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Archangels#) of Revelation (8:2) are named as Michael, Gabriel, Raphael, Suriel, Zadkiel, Sarathiel, and Ananiel.

> The Seven Archangels: Archangel Michael, Archangel Gabriel, Archangel Raphael, Archangel Suriel, Archangel Zadkiel, Archangel Sarathiel, Archangel Ananiel - [Source](https://st-takla.org/Full-Free-Coptic-Books/FreeCopticBooks-014-Various-Authors/001-Al-Mala2ka/The-Angels__39-Other-Archangels.html)